# How to print full array inside a block or outside block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Hello I have an array of floats, but I just can't print the full array

here's the first block which saves successfully the floats into the array floatDataArray

```
  double valuesArray[882000];
double *floatDataArray = valuesArray;
__block int j = 0;
//sampleInfo.size = 0;
[AEAudioFileReader readFileAtURL:amen.url targetAudioDescription:desc readBlock: ^(const AudioBufferList *buffer,UInt32(mBufferBlock)){


    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = buffer->mBuffers[0];

   float *samplesAsCArray = (float *)audioBuffer.mData;
    printf("\n%i", buffer->mBuffers[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i<mBufferBlock; i++) {
        floatDataArray[j] = (double)samplesAsCArray[i] ; //PUT YOUR DATA INTO FLOAT ARRAY
     //   printf("\n%f",floatDataArray[j]);  //PRINT YOUR ARRAY'S DATA IN FLOAT FORM RANGING -1 TO +1

        i++;
        j++;
    }
```

Then the completion block where it goes thru all the buffers first

```
 } completionBlock:^(NSError* error){

       printf("\n%@",floatDataArray);  //Print full array


}];
```

which I'm able to print single values such as floatDataArray[0] but not the full one it sends nothing using %@, %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print a C array of floats you will need to write a function to do so. You can't use `printf` or `NSLog` to print a C array without writing a for loop

If you were to uncomment the `printf` line in your top block of code you'd see your array. However, if you really have 882,000 entries in the array printing them all to the console will take a LOOOOOOOOOOOOONG time, and not be very useful.

```
for (int i = 0; i<mBufferBlock; i++) {
    printf("\n%f", floatDataArray[i]
}
```

You might want to limit the output to a fixed number of digits to make the output file smaller. If you use 6 digits of precision:

```
for (int i = 0; i<mBufferBlock; i++) {
    printf("\n%06f", floatDataArray[i]
}
```

Then you'll have 9 bytes of output for values <10, plus another byte/value for each extra integer digit in your value (1000.000001 would take 12 bytes, including the carriage return at the end.) If all the output takes 12 bytes, that means your output log file would be about 10.5 mb. That's a **LOT** of text.

Comment: Thank you very much,
Well, I just want to print to debug and see the result maybe a sample, but I dont really need print, I'm doing some signal processing to the array so I just need to know that the array is there :) But yeah the array is almost 80k long from audio

Comment: maybe I should use a NSMutableArray instead

Comment: Your array is 882k of floats, not 80 k. At least that's what it looks like from the code you posted.

Comment: NSMutableArrays are a LOT slower than C arrays, and you'd have to create 882k of NSNumbers to put in that array, and create new NSNumbers if you calculate new values. This would be easier in Swift, which has native support for arrays of Floats (or Doubles)

Comment: I see I'm using objective c/swift in this project so maybe I can pass that c array to a swift and the plot it :)

Answer (score 0):

printf can't print an array. Try:

`NSLog(@"%@", floatDataArray);`

Comment: floatDataArray is a C array of floats. That won't work.